# How achieve mulitple SP Online O365 Group Sites with same permissions as other sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, azure-ad

I understand that O365 Group SP sites are the way forward as it allows connectivity to other apps.
I would like to achieve a multiple SP sites to be controlled from a single permissions group, rather that every site having independent control.

I know I can add an AD/Azure group into a SP Group, but these users are then not synced to the O365 Group, and therefore not visible on the home page 'Members' link, and will cause confusion.

Is it possible where a global group of some kind can be associated to multiple SP sites, so that the 'Members' link on the home page contains these users? - Another explanation, can numerous SharePoint sites have the same O365 Group associated with it?

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently supported. A group connected team site is a one to one relationship e.g. one Microsoft 365 group to one SharePoint site.

As mentioned in your question, I would recommend using Azure AD security groups for this requirement and surfacing the members of that group in a different way.

Comment: Appreciate your reply, Would you know if this is documented anywhere ?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/learn-about-microsoft-365-groups-b565caa1-5c40-40ef-9915-60fdb2d97fa2

Comment: I couldn't find the relavent information in this link, did I miss it?

Comment: Microsoft have not provided any documentation that they support the scenario you're describing, only that one Microsoft 365 group can be connected to one SharePoint site. They do mention that it's not possible with subsites (primarily because a site can be connected to a group and have subsites): https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/transform/modernize-connect-to-office365-group-subsites